# Accidentally sent ETH to VEN Wallet

Tags: coinbase, wallet-transfer

Another "I accidentally sent x to y... question"

I sent some ETH from Coinbase to a VEN Wallet on hitbtc. I meant to send it to my ETH wallet on hitbtc so I could buy VEN. Coinbase is showing that the transaction was successful.

I've reached out to both services explaining what happened, and wondering what my recourse is. Several people have told me that I might be ok since VEN is an erc20 token.

Any idea what's going to happen? It's been about 30 minutes and nothing is showing up over on hitbtc.

https://www.etherchain.org/tx/3bfc8bcfda34841ba778eb20fa2a72389ba80fcd9d88538ed5c351f5f183622b

Comment: Hi there. Your best bet is to wait for responses from the support folks. You'll likely only get speculative answers here, which probably won't be much help.

Comment: This question was put on hold as off-topic, but I still think it's valuable to update (even though I can't do it as an official answer). This particular mistake seems like it will be reversible (it'll take 2 months and cost $100). https://support.hitbtc.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005447669-Recovery-of-mistakenly-sent-deposits

Comment: That's actually quite useful - I hadn't realised exchanges would charge for recovery (in cases where it's possible), though I suppose it makes sense. Thanks for following up :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the transaction was successful, its a matter of knowing what entity controls the private key of [0xfd3a4db33e79b4b788805700d69568ffcb1ca079](https://etherscan.io/address/0xfd3a4db33e79b4b788805700d69568ffcb1ca079).
That is where the ETH is stored and to whom the concerns should be addressed.